# Is there a way to get from the model and display the count of images per advert that a user posted

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the total count of images per each advert that was posted by a user. I want to display this count on my template. I have tried several solutions online to see if I could get this to work but I have kind of hit a brick wall. It's something I see on e-commerce sites; so I know it is possible. Please help...

```
My Model

class Advert(models.Model):
    """All adverts"""

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=49)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    image_primary = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="product_pictures", verbose_name='Image (required)')
    image_2 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="product_pictures", blank=True, null=True)
    image_3 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="product_pictures", blank=True, null=True)
    image_4 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="product_pictures", blank=True, null=True)
    image_5 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="product_pictures", blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
my View

def view_all(request):
    """View All view"""
    view_all_list = Advert.objects.all().order_by('date_posted')
    context = {
        "view_all_list": view_all_list
    }
    return render(request, 'view-all.html', context)
```

```
my template 

{% for items in view_all_list %}
    <a href="" class="col card-sm">
      <div class=" row">
        <span class="numbertext"><i style="margin-right: 4px;" class="fas fa-camera"></i>{{items.****}}</span>
        <img src="{{items.image_primary.url}}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row" title="{{items.title}} | {{items.price}}">
        <h5>{{items.title}}</h5>
        <h4>{{items.price}}</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

I want to get the total count of all the images so that I can use it here

`{{items.****}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, add something like this as a model method:

```
class Advert(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def image_count(self):
        image_count = 1
        if self.image_2:
            image_count += 1
        if self.image_3:
            image_count += 1
        if self.image_4:
            image_count += 1
        if self.image_5:
            image_count += 1
        return image_count
```

And in your template:

```
{{ items.image_count }}
```

However, this doesn't seem like a very good database schema. Instead it would make more sense (to me) to have another model, e.g.

```
class AdvertImage(models.Model):
    advert = models.ForeignKey(
        Advert,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='images',
    )
    image = models.ImageField()
```

This way you can:

1. Have as many images as you want (but still enforce a maximum per advert, perhaps in form validation or using formsets).
2. Simply do something like `advert.images.count()` to get the number of images, or in a template: `{{ advert.images.count }}`.
3. Have less repetitive code.

Comment: Thank-you so much Tom.